# Meteor app not working on chrome mobile but works everywhere else

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, meteor

My app located at:
Draftfantasyfootball.co.uk
works on all browsers as far as I can tell except for chrome mobile and I have no idea why or how to debug the problem.

When going to the site, it's constantly in logging in and it's impossible to do anything such as sign up or login.

Debugging advice would be helpful

Comment: I know this is really old, but did you solve the issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I no longer have the problem. Try opening in an incognito window or another phone and see if it still happens. Also you can debug by connecting to your computer and loading chrome

Comment: i'm wondering if your issue may have been related to recent chrome updates. i recently had problems with iron router and the latest update of chrome

Answer (score 1):

Its happening due to your appcache. You were probably coding it and loaded it on your smartphone. But then changed the code and its unable to update to the newer version properly.

Its trying to connect to update itself but the appcache or something there has changed and it keeps retrying. This may have caused it:

- Maybe you removed `appcache` and added it back?
- You might have a web proxy or something where its error page became cached instead (no Data balance/maybe a login page? - sometimes errors return 200 OK HTTP codes)

If you clear your chrome's cache/temporary offline data it should fix itself.

Comment: Didn't work. Does anyone with meteor experience know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my app at tomsabin.co.uk. I am using the `iron router` and `iron router progress` packages and the app loaded fine on iOS Safari and an Android device using Chrome, however the site failed to load in iOS Chrome - the progress bar would hang at 95%.

After a bit of research I thought the problem existed in the `iron router` package (see https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/498), however, I could visit another Meteor app with both `iron router` packages using iOS Chrome absolutely fine. The only difference I could see was the version numbers.

The other app was using `Meteor v0.7.2`, `Iron Router v0.6.4` and my app (tomsabin.co.uk) was using `Meteor v0.8.0` and `Iron Router v0.7.1`. I specified the older versions in my old app and checked whether it worked on iOS Chrome, and low and behold it worked. I'm trying to investigate further as to what may have caused this problem since these updated packages.

Comment: My site has this problem on Metoer v0.7.2 and old versions of Iron-Router so I'm not sure it's related to version no.